# Unwanted Azure webapp redirection

Tags: redirect, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have mapped a domain evangelical.sg to use azure webapp custom domain. However it looks like the domain only redirect to https://efosingapore-wp.azurewebsites.net/

I've checked with domain support, they claim the problem is with azure settings somewhere.
I've set the "custom domain" settings on azure webapp correctly to evangelical.sg (although it still hasnt got SSL) yet the URL seems to still redirect.

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong, and how to fix this pls?

Comment: Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=cname, in particular, pay attention to TXT and A record. Don't use the Vodien DNS redirection feature.

Comment: Use https://help.vodien.com/articles/dns-records-domain-name-system/ to create the records

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is redirecting to Tutorial ,
Try to redeploy the app by Deleting all the files, stopping the server, starting it again and then republish.

If you are facing any issues with TLS / SSL mapping , try to Map Custom Domain by following the below steps.

**Map Custom Domain:**
Go to Azure Portal
Select App Services- ->Select Your Azure App

1. Click on "+ Add Custom Domain"
2. Enter the domain and click on validate.
3. Add CNAME and TXT records in your DNS domain to verify domain ownership.
4. Click on "Add Custom Domain"

After adding the custom domain, the custom domain is still unsecure. You need to add the SSL certificate.

To add SSL certificate, please follow below procedure :

1. Go to TLS / SSL settings and click on "+ Add TLS / SSL Binding"
2. Select your custom domain and import the .pfx or public certificate for you domain and click Add.
3. Go to Custom Domains section and click on "Add binding".
4. Select the certificate of your domain and TLS/SSL type as SNI.
5. Click on "Add binding"